# Output with zabbix-api value history

Tags: python, zabbix

I am trying to capture the following sequence with the zabbix `hostid -> itemid -> history` API, but it has not returned anything to me. I need this script to return the last values ​​collected by ZABBIX, including item id + hostname

**SCRIPT**

```
from zabbix.api import ZabbixAPI
from datetime import datetime
import time

zapi = ZabbixAPI(url='http://192.168.1.250/zabbix', user='Admin', password='zabbix')

fromTimestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple()))
tillTimestamp = int(fromTimestamp - 60 * 60 * 1)  # 1 hours

# Get only the host of the specified hostgroup
hosts =  zapi.host.get(groupids='15',output='extend')

for host in hosts:
    items = zapi.item.get(itemid='28689', host=host['host'], output='extend' )
    for item in items:
        values = zapi.history.get(itemids=item['itemid'], time_from=fromTimestamp, time_till=tillTimestamp, output='extend')        
        for historyValue in values:
            print(host['host'],item['itemid'],historyValue['value'])
```

**OUTPUT**

Nothing returns me

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
'host','28689','84'
'host','28689','82'
'host','28689','85'
'host','28689','83'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues on your code (static `itemid`, missing params in the `history.get` etc...), I'll try to sum up everything.

You are filtering by a static hostgroup id, so I assume that you have more than one host and you want the value of a specific item of each host, something like:

- hostgroup: MyHostGroup
- members: host01, host02, host03
- item of interest: ICMP Loss

The output should be something like:

```
Timestamp  Hostname   ItemID   ICMP Loss
xxxxxx1    host01     10011    0
xxxxxx2    host01     10011    10
xxxxxx3    host01     10011    10
xxxxxx4    host01     10011    15

xxxxxx1    host02     10026    100
xxxxxx2    host02     10026    100
xxxxxx3    host02     10026    100
xxxxxx4    host02     10026    100

xxxxxx1    host03     10088    0
xxxxxx2    host03     10088    10
xxxxxx3    host03     10088    0
xxxxxx4    host03     10088    0
```

A working python implementation:

```
groupFilter = {'name': 'MyHostGroup'}
itemFilter = {'name': 'ICMP Loss'}

# Get the hostgroup id by its name 
hostgroups = zapi.hostgroup.get(filter=groupFilter, output=['groupids', 'name'])

# Get the hosts of the hostgroup by hostgroup id
hosts = zapi.host.get(groupids=hostgroups[0]['groupid'])

for host in (hosts):
    # Get the item info (not the values!) by item name AND host id
    items = zapi.item.get(filter=itemFilter, host=host['host'], output='extend', selectHosts=['host', 'name'])

    # for loop - for future fuzzy search, otherwise don't loop and use items[0] 
    for item in items:
        # Get item values
        values = zapi.history.get(itemids=item['itemid'], time_from=fromTimestamp, time_till=tillTimestamp, history=item['value_type'])

        for historyValue in values:
            print( ......... ) # format here your output, values are stored in historyValue['value']
```

Comment: Your answer was perfect, just a question, how can I correctly capture the variables fromTimestamp and tillTimestamp, without having to turn it into INT?

Comment: You **have** to turn them into INT, the `history.get` call supports timestamps only. I use this piece of code:  `fromTimestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(args.f, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").timetuple()))` to convert a date into the corresponding timestamp.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ChillyMiniatureCable How to deploy this in my code, please? Returned argument error

Comment: Substitute `args.f` with a date string formatted accordingly to the `strptime` call, see https://repl.it/repls/DefiantLovelyFolder