# Create zabbix sql table for each item

Tags: sql, postgresql, zabbix

I'm having trouble creating the output from Zabbix tables. I would like to output NAME(hosts), icmpping, icmploss for example.

So i would like something like this:

| hostname | ip | ping | loss | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test.server.1 | 1.1.1.1 | 0ms | 0% | up |
| test.server.2 | 8.8.8.8 | 1ms | 33% | up |

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

you can create a query to join the tables manually but the recommended way to get the data from zabbix is using the API.
[this question "Output with zabbix-api value history"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600238/output-with-zabbix-api-value-history) looks like a usable example to get it.

The [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/en/manual/api/reference/history/get) is pretty good and is worth reading.

For grafana is a zabbix plugin available that can be of help if you want to use grafana for visualization. See https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app/

Comment: im looking to visualize it on grafana.
what is the best way to using an API?

Comment: @SamukaSampaio grafana has a plug-in for zabbix.

Comment: yes, but cant create columns like described.
Tryed alot transformations... the option was using boomtable

Comment: @SamukaSampaio sorry, I can not help with grafana. Does your zabbix api user have the needed privileges?

Comment: yes i done some basic stuffs with the API